# How to make discrete gradient color bar with geom_contour_filled?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I plot a map based on a piece of code like this:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(y=eruptions, x=waiting, z=100*density)) +
geom_contour_filled(breaks = c(-Inf,-2., -1.5, -1., -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11,Inf))+
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10,hjust = 0.5))
```

This is my plot currently looks like:
[image]
But my boss asks me to make the legend like this:
[image]
or like this:[image]
Arguments from this link (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) just provide minor changes for the legend. And I can't find any arguments that can achieve this, is it doable with ggplot? or I have to use other plotting package?

[Create discrete color bar with varying interval widths and no spacing between legend levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506832/create-discrete-color-bar-with-varying-interval-widths-and-no-spacing-between-le) This question (answer No. 4) provides a method that can create a color bar like my boss required, however, I'm using `geom_contour_filled(breaks = c(-Inf,-2., -1.5, -1., -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11,Inf))` this argument so the legend always appears with a lot of text:
[image]
Are there any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create discrete color bar with varying interval widths and no spacing between legend levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506832/create-discrete-color-bar-with-varying-interval-widths-and-no-spacing-between-le)

Comment: Sorry have little time. I think this link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032513/ggplot2-legend-to-bottom-and-horizontal  ;
Also, here's a generic tutorial on labels: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-legend-easy-steps-to-change-the-position-and-the-appearance-of-a-graph-legend-in-r-software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is different enough to my previous answer to justify a second one. I answered the latter in complete denial of the new scale functions that came with ggplot2 3.3.0, and now here we go, they make it much easier. I'd still keep the other solution because it might help for ... well very specific requirements.

We still need to use metR because the problem with the continuous/discrete contour persists, and metR::geom_contour_fill handles this well.

I am modifying the `scale_fill_fermenter` function which is the good function to use here because it works with a binned scale. I have slightly enhanced the underlying `brewer_pal` function, so that it gives more than the original brewer colors, if `n > max(palette_colors)`.

**update**
You should use `guide_colorsteps` to change the colorbar. And [see this related discussion](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4019)  regarding the longer breaks at start and end of the bar.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(metR)

mybreaks <- c(seq(-2,2,0.5), 3:5, seq(7,11,2))

ggplot(faithfuld, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  metR::geom_contour_fill(aes(z = 100*density)) +
  scale_fill_craftfermenter(
    breaks = mybreaks, 
    palette = "Spectral", 
    limits = c(-2,11),
    guide = guide_colorsteps(
      frame.colour = "black", 
      ticks.colour = "black", # you can also remove the ticks with NA
      barwidth=20)
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
#> Warning: 14 colours used, but Spectral has only 11 - New palette created based
#> on all colors of Spectral
```

[image]

```r
## with uneven steps, better representing the scale 
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  metR::geom_contour_fill(aes(z = 100*density)) +
  scale_fill_craftfermenter(
    breaks = mybreaks, 
    palette = "Spectral", 
    limits = c(-2,11),
    guide = guide_colorsteps(
      even.steps = FALSE,
      frame.colour = "black", 
      ticks.colour = "black", # you can also remove the ticks with NA
      barwidth=20, )
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
#> Warning: 14 colours used, but Spectral has only 11 - New palette created based
#> on all colors of Spectral
```

[image]

**Function modifications**

```
craftbrewer_pal <- function (type = "seq", palette = 1, direction = 1) 
{
  pal <- scales:::pal_name(palette, type)
  force(direction)
  function(n) {
    n_max_palette <- RColorBrewer:::maxcolors[names(RColorBrewer:::maxcolors) == palette]
    
    if (n < 3) {
      pal <- suppressWarnings(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, pal))
    } else if (n > n_max_palette){
      rlang::warn(paste(n, "colours used, but", palette, "has only",
                    n_max_palette, "- New palette created based on all colors of", 
                    palette))
      n_palette <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n_max_palette, palette)
      colfunc <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(n_palette)
      pal <- colfunc(n)
    }
    else {
      pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, pal)
    }
    pal <- pal[seq_len(n)]
    if (direction == -1) {
      pal <- rev(pal)
    }
    pal
  }
}

scale_fill_craftfermenter <- function(..., type = "seq", palette = 1, direction = -1, na.value = "grey50", guide = "coloursteps", aesthetics = "fill") {
  type <- match.arg(type, c("seq", "div", "qual"))
  if (type == "qual") {
    warn("Using a discrete colour palette in a binned scale.\n  Consider using type = \"seq\" or type = \"div\" instead")
  }
  binned_scale(aesthetics, "fermenter", ggplot2:::binned_pal(craftbrewer_pal(type, palette, direction)), na.value = na.value, guide = guide, ...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tjebo. I'm just a beginner in R coding and I believe I will go back to your post again since it's super useful. I would like to send both of the two versions to my boss (the even step method is his original requirement). But for the two answer you gave on the even step solutions, I think the legend doesn't match the plot. For faithfuld, there is no data that smaller than 0 in the dataset, but your plot shows the minimum is between -1 and 0.5. It's also the same for my plot. I'm confused about that.

Comment: Also, you mentioned creating a reproducible example in your previous comments. I'm brand new to this website, and as a beginner in coding, I also know the importance of having a reproducible example. so thanks for telling me that!

Comment: @LambertYe see update, the problem was that one needs to use `guide_colorsteps`. (I did not think of rescaling the variable if I wanted to use custom breaks... But this workaround is not necessary anymore)

Answer (score 3):

**edit**

I recommend not to use this answer - my second answer in this thread is much more appropriate, but I have answered this here in ignorance of the new functions. I still think it may be useful in very specific situations, so I leave it for future readers. The functions are taken and modified taken from [Claus Wilke's comment in this github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2673#issuecomment-402878574).

I'd also like to again recommend to consider [user AF7's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50540633/7941188) to create a fake legend, because you have much more freedom how to style your legend.

`geom_contour_filled` discretizes your dimension of interest and then the inherently *continuous* `scale_fill_discrete_gradient` fails. It seems that `metR::geom_contour_fill` does not produce discrete data, but keeps it continous...

In order to make this solution work, you need to cut your variable to bins and then use the factor levels for setting breaks and limits. It's a bit hacky...

```r
library(RColorBrewer)
library(metR)
library(ggplot2)

mybreaks <- c(seq(-2,2,0.5), 3:5, seq(7,11,2))
mycols <- rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral"))(length(mybreaks)-1))
faithfuld$cut_dens <- cut(100*faithfuld$density, mybreaks)

ggplot(faithfuld, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  geom_contour_fill(aes(z = as.integer(cut_dens))) +
  scale_fill_discrete_gradient(
    colours = mycols,
    breaks = seq(1, 15, 1), # breaks and limits based on factor levels! 
    limits = c(1,15),
    bins = length(mybreaks)-1,
    labels = mybreaks,
    guide = guide_colourbar(frame.colour = "black", 
                            ticks.colour = "black", # you can also remove the ticks with NA
                            barwidth=20)
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

functions

```
## very mildly modified from Claus Wilke
discrete_gradient_pal <- function(colours, bins = 5) {
  ramp <- scales::colour_ramp(colours)
  
  function(x) {
    if (length(x) == 0) return(character())
    
    i <- floor(x * bins)
    i <- ifelse(i > bins-1, bins-1, i)
    ramp(i/(bins-1))
  }
}

scale_fill_discrete_gradient <- 
  function(..., colours, bins = 5, 
           na.value = "grey50", 
           guide = "colourbar", 
           aesthetics = "fill", colors)  {
    colours <- if (missing(colours)) 
      colors
    else colours
    continuous_scale(
      aesthetics,
      "discrete_gradient",
      discrete_gradient_pal(colours, bins),
      na.value = na.value,
      guide = guide,
      ...
    )
  }
```

Comment: Hi Tjebo, thank you so much. I'm not sure if you remember you helped me out on this question [How to customize a color palette in r for ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62462030/how-to-customize-a-color-palette-in-r-for-ggplot).
I tried for several times, but still can't find how to introduce your argument into my code, it seems there's some conflict with "geom_contour_filled". Actually, I also tried other codes that can modify legend, but most of them don't work when I use "geom_contour_filled"

Comment: @LambertYe Sure I do remember and it was fun to answer. It  would massivley help me (and everyone else here!) if you could try to create a reproducible example. This includes also sharing some data with which you want to create the filled contours. Usually you don't need to post the full data, but just the minimal columns and some data points to create, well, in this case, a contour.

Comment: @LambertYe Also check out the package metR https://github.com/eliocamp/metR which may seem to provide something very along the lines what you want to do. and check the github thread to which I linked in my post above, and also truly this function from Adriano!

Answer (score 3):

This is an old answer, but the `metR` package might solve this issue with the new discretised scale (disclaimer, I'm the author :) ). Use `ggplot2::geom_contour_filled()` (or `metR::geom_contour_fill(aes(fill = stat(level)))`) and then use `metR::scale_fill_discretised()`

```r
library(ggplot2)

breaks <-  c(-Inf,-2., -1.5, -1., -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11,Inf)
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(y=eruptions, x=waiting, z=100*density)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = breaks) +
  metR::scale_fill_discretised()
```

[image]

This will treat discretised values (such as the computed `level` variable from `geom_contour_filled()`) as if they were continuous. Notice that now the colour scale correctly reflects the unequal spacing of the breaks. That is, not only the breaks are unequally spaced in the guide, but also the colours are unequally spaced in the colour scale.

If you want to use a colour palette similar to the ones on your screenshot, you can
use `ggplot2::scale_fill_gradientn()` but convert it to a discretised scale with the
`super` argument.

```r
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(y=eruptions, x=waiting, z=100*density)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = breaks) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("#0A2864", "#CCD9FF", "#FFF9CF", "#FEBF00", "#E6281E", "#6C0000"),
    super = metR::ScaleDiscretised)
```

[image]

Or any other continuous scale.

```r
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(y=eruptions, x=waiting, z=100*density)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = breaks) +
  scale_fill_distiller(super = metR::ScaleDiscretised, palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

And from that, just continue with any adjustments as you see fit.

(This feature is a bit new and it might have errors on cases I didn't considered. If you use it and find any problem, please do [open an issue in the github repository](https://github.com/eliocamp/metR/issues). I'd be glad to solve it.)

<sup>Created on 2020-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to make use of `guide_bins`.

To get nice labels you can probably make use of the `labels` argument to `cut` as I do in my approach.

Unfortunately I could not figure out a way to remove the spacing between the legend keys or to have a black frame around the keys.

Also, without a glance at your data and color palette I'm not sure whether this approach could be easily adpated to your case.

```r
set.seed(42)

d <- data.frame(
  x = runif(1000, -20, 20)
)

d$y <- cut(d$x, breaks = c(-Inf, seq(-2, 11, 1), Inf), labels = c(seq(-2, 11, 1), ""))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(y, fill = as.numeric(y))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_viridis_b(name = "\u00B0C", limits = c(-2, 11), breaks = seq(-2, 11, 1),
                       guide = guide_bins(axis = FALSE, title.position = "right",
                                          axis.colour = "black",
                                          keywidth = unit(1, "cm"), 
                                          keyheight = unit(1, "cm"))) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, the ggplot version 3.3.0 might solve all your problems (as shown in part [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/)). metR package seems to be no longer needed. Although the question is old, this might help future readers. You can use the `guide_colorsteps` function to change from the "interval" labels to the labels we are familiar with. I used the RColorBrewer package as I think it's the best option if you want to use the "Spectral" palette (as it doesn't contain enough colors for the example), but it's not necessary depending on your palette needs (as explained bellow).

```
Spectral.colors <- colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "Spectral"))
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(y=eruptions, x=waiting, z=100*density)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = c(-Inf,-2., -1.5, -1., -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11,Inf)) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10,hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(Spectral.colors(16)),drop=FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorsteps(direction = "horizontal",
                                 barwidth = unit(par("pin")[1], "in"))) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: asked_plot]

In the above example, `scale_fill_manual` have two inputs, `values` and `drop`. `values` is a vector with all used colors (with length 16 as breaks have length 17) and `drop=FALSE` ensures all your breaks will be shown (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64880867/14874374)). Then `guides` and `theme` are adjustments to make a nice bottom horizontal legend. In particular, `barwidth` is the width of your legend. If not given, its width might be too small. `par("pin")[1]` will take the current plot width in inches, but you can specify a specific value if you want.

If the length of your breaks is small enough, you can replace `scale_fill_manual(values = rev(Spectral.colors(16)),drop=FALSE)` by `scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral",drop=FALSE)`. If you don't need to use "Spectral" and want to use the original `geom_contour_filled` palette ("viridis"), the same chunk can be replaced by `scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE)`. And finally, if you want to change the palette to any other except "viridis" and "Spectral", you can try the R build-in palette creator functions (e.g., `heat.colors`). The same chunk can be replaced by `scale_fill_manual(values = heat.colors(16),drop=FALSE)`.

If you need the legend to be in its the original place (vertical), your code should be (here I used `heat.colors` just for illustration):

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(y=eruptions, x=waiting, z=100*density)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = c(-Inf,-2., -1.5, -1., -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11,Inf)) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10,hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = heat.colors(16),drop=FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorsteps(barheight = unit(par("pin")[2], "in")))
```

[image: vertical_legend_alternative]

Where `barwidth` was replaced by `barheight` and `par("pin")[1]` was replaced by `par("pin")[2]`.