# Continuous color bar with separators instead of ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

The picture should give a good idea of what I would want to achieve. Ideally, the resulting colour bar would keep a continuous nature, i.e., should be based on a continuous rather than discrete aesthetic, or at least come very close to behave like it.

This also means, not just the simple approach of just bringing the legend keys of a discrete fill close enough together.

[Yes, I could create a fake legend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50540633/7941188), but I'd like a solution that modifies at the legend drawing level.

I would be also very happy with interesting grid hacks!

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Petal.Length))+
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_continuous() +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(ticks.colour = "black"))
```

<sub>That's photoshopped, apologies!. I don't want to create the arrow, just the continuous scale with separators instead of ticks</sub>
[image]

The ultimate goal is to reproduce a color bar as [orignially proposed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62543112/7941188)
[image]

However, this is not about creating the discrete gradient bar, this is just about the separators!

The discrete gradient bar is not the problem, there are already solutions out there (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544405/7941188, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62556763/7941188, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50540633/7941188)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There definitely is an option with the extendable guide system introduced in ggplot v3.3.0. See example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

guide_longticks <- function(...) {
  guide <- guide_colorbar(...)
  class(guide) <- c("guide", "guide_longticks", "colorbar")
  guide
}

guide_gengrob.guide_longticks <- function(guide, theme) {
  dir <- guide$direction
  guide <- NextMethod()
  is_ticks <- grep("^ticks$", guide$layout$name)
  ticks <- guide$grobs[is_ticks][[1]]
  if (dir == "vertical") {
    ticks$x1 <- rep(tail(ticks$x1, 1), length(ticks$x1))
  } else {
    ticks$y1 <- rep(tail(ticks$y1, 1), length(ticks$y1))
  }
  
  guide$grobs[[is_ticks]] <- ticks
  guide
}

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Petal.Length))+
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_continuous() +
  guides(fill = guide_longticks(ticks = TRUE, ticks.colour = "black"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT:

Also try this alternative constructor if you want flat colours in between ticks:

```
guide_longticks <- function(...) {
  guide <- guide_colorsteps(...)
  class(guide) <- c("guide", "guide_longticks", "colorsteps", "colorbar")
  guide
}
```

EDIT2:

The following gengrob function would also delete the smaller ticks, if you want cleaner vector files. It kind of assumes that they are the last half of the ticks though:

```
guide_gengrob.guide_longticks <- function(guide, theme) {
  dir <- guide$direction
  guide <- NextMethod()
  is_ticks <- grep("^ticks$", guide$layout$name)
  ticks <- guide$grobs[is_ticks][[1]]
  n <- length(ticks$x0)
  if (dir == "vertical") {
    ticks$x0 <- head(ticks$x0, n/2)
    ticks$x1 <- rep(tail(ticks$x1, 1), n/2)
  } else {
    ticks$y0 <- head(ticks$y0, n/2)
    ticks$y1 <- rep(tail(ticks$y1, 1), n/2)
  }
  
  guide$grobs[[is_ticks]] <- ticks
  guide
}
```

Comment: Your questions are often more interesting to answer than 'how do I make this stacked barchart?' :)

Comment: As long as guides keep returning ticks in the current format, the edit above should remove the extra ticks.

Comment: Well at that point you already have a complete guide ready for drawing. It just needs to be positioned in the right place in the plot, but isn't modified any further.

Comment: hey Teun. Coming back to this after a few years and I guess some important changes in ggplot2. Running this code results in the error: "Error in as.vector(x, "character") :   cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'" I guess somewhere there is an ill-defined promise or even object x, but I cannot figure out where.

Comment: Yes, the guide system has been rewritten. The new colourbar guide now has a `ticks.length` option that should replace the fussyness of the above approach, but for some reason it doesn't work.  Might be best to post an issue that the argument isn't working as advertised.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your swift response!

Comment: @tjebo should now be fixed in ggplot2 dev version.

Answer (score 5):

There's certainly a quick grid hack Tjebo, but it probably needs a bit of work to make it robust (indexing by name rather than by number):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, fill = Petal.Length))+
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_continuous() +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(ticks.colour = "black"))

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))

x1 <- gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "guide-box")]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[5]]$x1
x1[1:7] <- x1[8:14]
gt$grobs[[which(gt$layout$name == "guide-box")]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[5]]$x1 <- x1
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think that was the right decision @Tjebo. Teunbrand's answer is more complete and generalizable.