# Add a long tick to a specific break in ggplot2 guide_colorsteps()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is an example:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) + 
  geom_contour_filled() +
  guides(fill = guide_colorsteps()) +
  geom_contour(color = "black", breaks = c(0.03))
```

[image]
I want to add a long tick to a specific break (here it is 0.03) on the color scale to help interpretation, just like the black contour line.
I found a close solution made by [@teunbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11374827/teunbrand) in [Continuous color bar with separators instead of ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62558043/continuous-color-bar-with-separators-instead-of-ticks) :

```
guide_longticks <- function(...) {
  guide <- guide_colorsteps(...)
  class(guide) <- c("guide", "guide_longticks", "colorsteps", "colorbar")
  guide
}

guide_gengrob.guide_longticks <- function(guide, theme) {
  dir <- guide$direction
  guide <- NextMethod()
  is_ticks <- grep("^ticks$", guide$layout$name)
  ticks <- guide$grobs[is_ticks][[1]]
  n <- length(ticks$x0)
  if (dir == "vertical") {
    ticks$x0 <- head(ticks$x0, n/2)
    ticks$x1 <- rep(tail(ticks$x1, 1), n/2)
  } else {
    ticks$y0 <- head(ticks$y0, n/2)
    ticks$y1 <- rep(tail(ticks$y1, 1), n/2)
  }
  
  guide$grobs[[is_ticks]] <- ticks
  guide
}

ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) + 
  geom_contour_filled() +
  guides(fill = guide_longticks(ticks = TRUE, ticks.colour = "black")) +
  geom_contour(color = "black", breaks = c(0.03))
```

[image]
However this solution adds ticks to all breaks, but I just want a tick at 0.03.

I appreciate answers that keep geom_contour_filled() and guide_colorsteps()!

Comment: Could you provide a data sample (for instance `dput(faithfuld)`) so that we could debug?

Comment: Hi @asd-tm I think `faithfuld ` is built in ggplot2, so `library(ggplot2)` then `faithfuld` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer the following workaround suitable for the specific case:

```
guide_gengrob.guide_longticks <- function(guide, theme) {
  dir <- guide$direction
  guide <- NextMethod()
  is_ticks <- grep("^ticks$", guide$layout$name)
  ticks <- guide$grobs[is_ticks][[1]]
  n <- length(ticks$x0)
  if (dir == "vertical") {
    ticks$x0 <- head(ticks$x0, n/2)
    ticks$x1 <- rep(tail(ticks$x1, 1), n/2)
    ticks$x1[-6] <- unit(0,"cm") # ---- Added this line ----
  } else {
    ticks$y0 <- head(ticks$y0, n/2)
    ticks$y1 <- rep(tail(ticks$y1, 1), n/2)
  }
  
  guide$grobs[[is_ticks]] <- ticks
  guide
}
```

[image]