# How to specify bin colors for plot_usmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, usmap

I'm looking to create a heat map with a little more control over the color scale, specifically I want to have bins for ranges of values that will correspond to a specific color.

Below I provide some sample code to generate some data and make a plot. The issue seems to be how it maps the colors to the breaks, it is not a 1:1 correspondence, when I add more percentiles to the breaks it seems to stretch the colors.

It does not appear to be a large issue here, but when I apply this to the entire US data set I'm working with the color scheme really breaks down.

```
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)

fips <- seq(45001,45091,2)
value <- rnorm(length(fips),3000,10000)
data <- data.frame(fips,value)
data$value[data$value<0]=0

plot_usmap(regions='counties',data=data,values="value",include="SC") +
  scale_fill_stepsn(breaks=c(as.numeric(quantile(data$value,seq(.25,1,.25)))),
                  colors=c("blue","green","yellow","red"))

plot_usmap(regions='counties',data=data,values="value",include="SC") +
  scale_fill_stepsn(breaks=c(as.numeric(quantile(data$value,seq(0,1,.1)))),
                    colors=c("blue","green","yellow","red"))
```

[image]

[image]

```
#data not provided for this bit
plot_usmap(regions='counties',data=datar,values="1969",exclude=c("AK","HI")) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(breaks=c(as.numeric(quantile(datar$`1969`,seq(0,1,.1)))),
                    colours=c("blue","green","yellow","red"))
```

[image]

Comment: scale_fill_continuous(
    low = "grey", high = "darkgreen", name = "USA MAP", label = scales::comma

Comment: "bins for ranges of values that will correspond to a specific color."

Comment: The data involves high percentiles that are much larger, so I want to use bins, not a continuous color scale

Comment: Funnily, there is a very similar thread just from a few days ago. Lucky me, that I left my first answer to this thread, because it should allow exactly for what you need: Create cuts, and then make breaks and labels depending on the resulting factor levels https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544405/7941188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to manually bin the percentiles and then use the factor levels for your manual breaks and labels.

I've never used this high level function from usmap, so I don't know how to deal with this warning which comes up. Would personally prefer and recommend to use `ggplot + geom_polygon` or friends for more control.

```r
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)

fips <- seq(45001,45091,2)
value <- rnorm(length(fips),3000,10000)
mydat <- base::data.frame(fips,value)
mydat$value[mydat$value<0]=0

mydat$perc_cuts <- as.integer(cut(ecdf(mydat$value)(mydat$value), seq(0,1,.25)))


plot_usmap(regions='counties',
           data=mydat,
           values="perc_cuts",include="SC") +
  scale_fill_stepsn(breaks= 1:4, limits = c(0,4), labels = seq(.25, 1, .25),
                    colors=c("blue","green","yellow","red"),
                    guide = guide_colorsteps(even.steps = FALSE))
#> Warning: Use of `map_df$x` is discouraged. Use `x` instead.
#> Warning: Use of `map_df$y` is discouraged. Use `y` instead.
#> Warning: Use of `map_df$group` is discouraged. Use `group` instead.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Tjebo, I think the manual cut idea is very helpful. I've been considering using ```ggplot + geom_polygon``` but I don't have any shp files on hand for that...so maybe ```plot_usmap``` was too much of a lazy shortcut.

Comment: @dobothor check out https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf-2.html and the part about the US may help you