# Keep same breaks across different contour plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I am creating contour plots of different subsets of my data using ggplot2 stat_contour_filled function. However, for each it produces different color scales, which makes it hard to compare them. I have tried using the "breaks=" option, but for some reason it does not work. A MWE is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

v <- list()
v[[1]] <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) + stat_contour_filled(breaks=(0:10)*0.005)
v[[2]] <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = 1.1*density)) + stat_contour_filled(breaks=(0:10)*0.005)

of = "mwe.png"
png(of)
print(do.call(grid.arrange,  v))
dev.off()
```

It produces the following plot[image: Result of the MWE].

How can I get the same color levels for both contour plots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that discrete scales drop empty levels. You can use `drop = FALSE` to tell the relevant scale to not drop empty levels.

```
library(ggplot2)

breaks <- (0:10)*0.005

ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) + 
  stat_contour_filled(breaks = (0:10)*0.005) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = 1.1*density)) + 
  stat_contour_filled(breaks = (0:10)*0.005) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Alternatively, you could set the limits explicitly. It's a bit awkward though because it requires turning the break values into formatted strings.

```
library(ggplot2)

make_break_labels <- function(breaks, digits = 3) {
  n <- length(breaks)
  interval_low <- breaks[1:(n-1)]
  interval_high <- breaks[2:n]
  label_low <- format(as.numeric(interval_low), digits = digits, trim = TRUE)
  label_high <- format(as.numeric(interval_high), digits = digits, trim = TRUE)
  sprintf("(%s, %s]", label_low, label_high)
}

breaks <- (0:10)*0.005
break_labels <- make_break_labels(breaks)

ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) + 
  stat_contour_filled(breaks = (0:10)*0.005) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_d(limits = break_labels)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = 1.1*density)) + 
  stat_contour_filled(breaks = (0:10)*0.005) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(limits = break_labels)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in `ggplot2`, maybe in the `iso_to_polygon` function here:  https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/b76fa9639215785f8e94874d3bdf02225bae898a/R/stat-contour.r#L284 .  If levels have no data in them (your first plot has nothing greater than 0.04, so the top two bands are empty), then they are silently discarded.

Edited again:

Here's a partial workaround.  If you specify the colour scale to use `drop = FALSE`, no levels will be dropped.  For example,

```
v <- list()
v[[1]] <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
          stat_contour_filled(breaks=(0:10)*0.005) +
          scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE)
v[[2]] <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = 1.1*density)) +
          stat_contour_filled(breaks=(0:10)*0.005) +
          scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE)
print(do.call(grid.arrange,  v))
```

Here I've set the colours to `scale_fill_viridis_d()`; choose a different palette if you like.  I don't know how to change the `drop` argument to `FALSE` without specifying a scale.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a bug. Scales by default drop empty factor levels, and a simple `drop=FALSE` in the scale prevents this from happening.

Comment: I would think that the default for a filled contour scale should be `drop = FALSE`, and no `scale_*` term should be needed.   It doesn't really make sense for a user to specify the breaks and have them ignored just because some bins are empty.  But I'll edit my answer to give a `drop = FALSE` workaround, which is better than the one I gave.